# date converted to Arabic numbers when app's language is Arabic

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

My app has two languages .. Arabic and English ..

And am getting todays date like this:

```
var todaydate = ""
var today = Date()
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
todaydate = formatter.string(from: today)
```

this returns in English:

> 2018-06-04

and in Arabic:

> ٢٠١٨-٠٦-٠٤

I want to be always in English numbers like 2018-06-04

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting local

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
```